# Create Virtual Host in Wamp

Tags: windows, apache2

I want to Create a virtual Host for my local website. I am using Wamp Server utility to run my php based sites and using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com and what's the problem?

Comment: Offtopic: question on configuring servers will get better chance to be answered on serverfault.com or maybe superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Place in your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file information about name of your localhost site (optional):

```
127.0.0.1        mysite.local
```

**2)** In your `c:\wamp\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf` under `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"` add this

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\sites\mysite"
</VirtualHost>
```

You must correct name of your server with hosts file